# Manipulate camera track motion

Tags: keyframes, tracking

I'm jumping from motion tracking in After Effects to learning motion tracking in Blender, and I've run into a problem.

Following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY8Ol2n4o4A), I've tracked my handheld footage and placed a camera into the scene. The camera is moving around the scene perfectly.

I want the camera to stop moving at the beginning and end of the shot. How can I do this?

In After Effects, an object with the tracked motion applied will have transform keyframes that can be manipulated. However, in Blender, it looks like the transform keyframes (Object Properties tab) are separate from the tracked motion applied on the camera.

Essentially I want to animate the camera, then have it follow the tracked handheld motion, then back to being animated. I assume the only way to do this is to remove the handheld motion at the beginning and end of the shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Camera > Animation > CameraAction
Object Constraint Properties tab

I keyframed the Influence value, setting it to 0 when I wanted the handheld motion turned off.